# spring gateway unable to start with feign client

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

Using Spring 2.7.0 to create an API gateway, that was working fine until I tried to replace the RestTemplate with OpenFeign.

Here is the relevant build.gradle contents:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.1.0'
    id 'groovy'
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.3")
}
    
//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'        
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"        
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
```

My application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class ApiGatewayApplication {
...
}
```

My FeignClient:

```
@FeignClient(name="identity-service")
public interface IdentityServiceClient {

    @GetMapping("/api/all")
    public List<ApiKey> getAllApiKeys();

}
```

when I try to start the application now I get:

```
o.s.c.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean   : For 'identity-service' URL not provided. Will try picking an instance via load-balancing.
   DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration : Eureka HTTP Client uses RestTemplate
    ....
   onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apiGatewayApplication': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is feign.codec.DecodeException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
 com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
 com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/192.168.1.72:api-gateway:8081 - deregister  status: 404
 com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
 


***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters' in your configuration.
```

But none of the online examples seem to show the need for adding custom HttpMessageConverters since they are included in spring-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux

**UPDATE** -
this appears to be related to @Autowired.  I put both my service and feign service in a regular class and it starts up fine.  But when I autowire those two services, I get this error again.

Comment: SC Gateway is webflux-based, while Spring Cloud OpenFeign is based on spring-web. This is probably causing the issue. Also, we usually recommend that Gateway be a standalone app, only with the routing config. Why do you need an HTTP client there?

Comment: I am using the Gateway to validate the AUTHORIZATION header against APIKeys (retrieved from different service) before routing.  If there is a better pattern I would love to know it.

Comment: Since I need the SC Gateway to have a cache of API Keys to validate, perhaps I just need to make this a OpenFeign/Boot project rather than a Gateway project?

Comment: Makes sense to have a client then - you could probably go with the Spring interface client (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.0-M4/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-http-interface-client) once Spring 6 has been released. For now, you could use Spring Cloud Square, but it'll only be supported throughout Spring Cloud 2021.0.x.